# React set focus to next inputField of next component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem. Component A consists of components B and C. 
Component B has **input1** and **input2**. I can move focus from input1 to input2 when some condition is met but i cant move focus from **input2** to **component C**. Component C contains some div that inside it contains among others an Input as it is presented below.

**COMPONENT A**

```
   (props) => {
   const nextInput = useRef(null);

   function goToNext(){
      props.focusBoolean = true;
   }


return (

    <div>
    <TimePicker24H 
        onLastInput={goToNext} 
    />
    <TextInput
        focusFromParent={ props.focusBoolean }            
        ref={nextInput}
    />
  </div>
);
```

**COMPONENT C**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
          **<Input >**
        </div>       
    )
}
```

The question is how can i move focus to {component C} when a condition is meet in {component A}??

Comment: Why not use a JavaScript event: componentA.onevent {componentC.focus}

Comment: can you be more detailed ? I dont fully understand what you are proposing